# sending multiple objects using axios

Tags: reactjs, json, axios

How can I send multiple objects in axios ? is there a way to send an array to an API using axios ?

This is the code.

```
export const addOrderAdmin = (ownerID,array) => api.patch(`/checkout/${ownerID}`,
    {
        delivery: array // array with 2 objects. 
    }
)
```

and the objects was like this.
[image]

is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean is it possible? Did you _try_ it? What happened?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: it's working .. it seems the problem is on my backend lmao.

Answer (score 0):

you could always create an array of nested objects

example:

```
var customerInfo = {
  name: 'bob',
  phone : 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
  address: [
   {
     id: 1,
     city: 'Buffalo'
   },
   {
     id 2,
     city: 'Houston'
  ]
}
```

then you could just patch the customerInfo object and you can use interpolation with dot accessor notation for the url